# JPA Entity with multiple resultsets having different columns

Tags: jpa

I am using JPA with derby database. I want to retrieve two different result sets from the same table onto two entirely different screens.

Screen one displays values using "ScannerReport" bean.

Screen two will display values from ScannerSummaryReport bean.

Both beans needs to have data from same Entity "Scanner" as mentioned in code below.

How to define that result set mapping onto the entity for two different result sets, having different columns in it

```
A --->    Query query = em.createNativeQuery(<query for scanner report goes here >,"ScannerReport");
          query.getResultList();
```

Now A will execute and instantiate an object of ScannerReport class , fill it up with data .

```
B --->    Query query = em.createNativeQuery(<query for scanner summary report goes here>,"ScannerSummaryReport");
           query.getResultList();
```

I want somehow to let JPA know that when i execute B, now it needs to instantiate an object of a different class lets say ScannerSummaryReport fill it up with data from A DIFFERENT QUERY ( written to calcuate averages and totals ) and return the result.Again please not both queries will be from same entity Scanner..

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
        name="ScannerReport",
        classes={
                @ConstructorResult(
                    targetClass=com.beans.ScannerReport.class,
                    columns={
                        @ColumnResult(name="scanYear", type=Integer.class),                     
                        @ColumnResult(name="julianDay", type=Integer.class),                        
                        @ColumnResult(name="scannerId", type=String.class),                                 
                        @ColumnResult(name="startTime", type=Long.class),                                   
                        @ColumnResult(name="endTime", type=Long.class),                                 
                        @ColumnResult(name="scanTime", type=Long.class),                                    
                    }
                )           
            }
        )
@Entity
public class Scanner  {

// Class implementation goes here

}
```

Comment: so you defined ScannerReport result set mapping, and haven't defined ScannerSummaryReport result set mapping. So perhaps do it? Don't see the problem

Comment: I need to define both, so that i can get both beans filled up with data ( from two different places ) but @SqlResultSetMapping does not allow me to define two mappings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So just define two SqlResultSetMappings, using the @SqlResultSetMappings annotation, one for each query. See http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_0/jpa/annotations.html#SqlResultSetMappings  for an example

Comment: Thanks! So simple! The error message made it sound like it was not possible to use more than one... should just have said wrap in `@SqlResultSetMappings` like your answer :)